# How to determine if a period of missing values is short or long

Tags: interpolation

I am dealing with a dataset that has some missing values. I read an article where it is stated that some imputation methods may work better in short periods of missing values, while others may provide better results when applied to long periods of missing values.

However, I could not find any "criteria" to determine whether a missing values period is short or long.

Any suggestion in this matter?
Thanks in advance

Comment: how do you know that some values are missing? is time/date is one of the fields in the dataset?

Comment: Yes it is. One of the fields is the datetime.